# Pegar valor de input para executar no loop for

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho o *input* `QtdParcela`, e quero que meu *loop* gere os dados até o valor digitado na *input*.

Segue parte de meu código:

No *for*, onde está `10`, quero que receba o valor que o usuário vai digitar. Como faço isso?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="QtdParcela">Quantidade Parcela</label>
      <input type="text" name="QtdParcela" id="QtdParcela" class="form-control">
</div>  

<button type="button" id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#bt_add').click(function(){
            adicionar();

      });
});

function adicionar(){

      for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)

      endfor
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> No for onde está 10, quero colocar o valor que o usuário vai colocar, como faço isso?

Basta passar o `value` do `input` como parâmetro pra sua função:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bt_add').click(function(){
            let parcelas = $('#QtdParcela').val();
            adicionar(parcelas);
        });
    });

    function adicionar(param1){
        for ($i = 0; $i < param1; $i++)

        endfor
    }

</script>
```

PS: Ignorei o restante do código!

Answer (score 0):

O código anterior não funcionou, porém conseguir resolver.
Esqueci de abrir e fechar {}

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < param1; $i++){

 }
 endfor
```

Comment: Nesse caso vc não utiliza o `endfor`! As chaves já delimitam o loop...